# FireBug 1.7.3 - turn off Break On Next, change to Break On Error?

Tags: breakpoints, firebug, break, onerror

Firebug 1.7.3. is stuck on Break on Next. Pressing F8 Continue just does the same thing as F10  Step Over since it breaks on the very next line! If I mouse over the bug icon, it says "break on next". Clicking on it changes nothing. It stays as "break on next".

Am I doing something wrong?
Is Firebug 1.7.3 broken?
How do I turn off "break on next"?  How do I keep it off?
How do I turn on "break on error"?  How do I force it to be on always?

Answer (score 0):

The "break on next" setting has been moved to the Console panel, on the pause button. It's illogical, IMHO, but there we are. I am using Firebug 1.10.6.